# Firebase App Distribtion AAB signing key?

Tags: android-app-bundle, firebase-app-distribution

I'd like to migrate to App Bundle for my prod build variant for Play store away from APKs.

Firebase App Distribution says it now supports distributing AABs, but needs a Google Play linked.

AABs are from what I gather, re-signed by the play store.

***Does that mean my firebase distributed AAB is signed with the same key play store uses*** - meaning I'd be able to test app update?

(app installed from play store and then updated via installing one from firebase - without uninstalling)